# Given Seed, keyfragment and cipher text, how to get actual text using LFSR?

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis

$\text{seed = 1100010001101001}$

$\text{key fragment = 110001010000101011001011111101100}$

$\text{cipher text =  0xa50b839547f7fe7cf882}$

What is the actual text and how to evaluate it? I would like to know the exact procedure to do it.

Comment: I went through that duplicate but I want more detailed explanation. Detailed explanation in the sense, workout that example and upload a pic or something...I got the polynomial to be x^16+ x^12+x^3+x+1. But i dont know what to do next

Comment: What kind of detailed explanation do you need? This is exactly the same question. The Berlekamp-Massey result is same. Only the seed and key fragment are different.

Comment: I've closed this, please indicate what you are missing in the answer given for the other question (*besides* the values being different) or ask a new / different question.